# Building a private API to connect with mobile app?

Tags: python, django, rest, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework

I'm attempting to build a private API to connect to my mobile app. One use would be to make a call with a string parameter, have the api run the string through several nlp python scripts, and return back some json. What would be a good place to start in terms of api services and resources?

So far I've heard that I can use Django Rest Framework for this, but I wanted to make sure to ask people with more experience. Also what's the best place to host it, including the scripts (my hosting with namecheap, amazon s3, etc)

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow - you're asking opinions on external resources (hosting), plus opinions on various frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

your question is very vague and short on details ... that said flask is probably the easiest to get up and running

```
import flask,json
from flask import request

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

def validate_headers_if_needed():
    print request.headers

def process_get_or_post_arguments():
    return dict(post = request.form.to_dict(),
                get = request.args.to_dict(),
                headers_auth=request.headers.get("X-Authorization","None"))

@app.route("/api/v0/do_something",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def do_something():
    validate_headers_if_needed()
    result = process_get_or_post_arguments()
    return json.dumps(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8787,debug=True)

# curl --header "X-Authorization: MySecretToken" --data "test1=55&test2=hello%20world%test3=1" http://127.0.0.1:8787/api/v0/do_something?get_data=yellow
```

when its time to pick a host you should choose one that meets your needs I like dreamhost alot ... however I have recently used digital ocean with great sucess ... you can also just run it on a local linux (or windows box) and use something like noip.com to point a domain name to your box

Comment: Thanks Joran! I've heard about using Python and Flask. I do have several questions about this though. Where would this be usually stored, I'm planning on using parse (database), and s3 (file storage). Mind you, I have little to no experience with backend, but need to know just enough to get my mvp up and running. Also, how secure is flask in terms of preventing third-party apps from using the private api?

Comment: as secure as you make it ... you would raise an AuthenticationError when validating if it did not meet any of your criteria ... you can run this anywhere you can install flask and run python ...

Comment: digital ocean works good ... its pretty easy to setup apache to server it (there are a million and one tutorials out there ...) or you could serve it with a more multithreaded application like gunicorn + nginx (Also a lot of tutorials but a little harder to setup)

Comment: in this example you can just run it locally to test until it works how you want (maybe a couple hours) ... then get it on a host

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87666/kingpolygons-questions-about-webstuff

Comment: https://github.com/lazToum/docker_flask_mongodb_gunicorn_nginx